# A Manga about some girl with chains in a Isekai

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

A long long time ago, I once read a manga on an app called “Manga Rock” about some girl with a dark blue high school uniform who had chains on her wrists, she had a connection to the other side of reality, where I can’t specifically tell if there were dragons or spirits she healed from evil. There was a boy too, I think he was the protagonist, but she was way cooler.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When was "a long long time ago?". Was this black-and-white or in colour?

Comment: This sound like rosario vampire ?